# Fragment getItem (int arg0) return a preferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

So basically what I am doing is using the following code with tabs. What I want to do is have one tab with a PreferenceFragment on it. However, it has to return a fragment.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (arg0 == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentNormal();
    }
    if (arg0 == 1) {
        fragment = new FragmentDifference();
    }
    if (arg0 == 2) {
        fragment = new FragmentSetup();
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

For if argo0==2, I need to do one of 2 things. First - return a fragment and make FragmentSetup extend Fragment not PreferenceFragment (then I have no idea how to show preferences)

OR

Somehow return a PrefererenceFragment.

Here is my code for the FragmentSetup (basically it just loads a basic layout with a textview things)

```
public FragmentSetup() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setup, container,
            false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource

}
```

}

Comment: The problem is dat `getItem()` wants you return an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, but an official `PreferenceFragment` only exists as an extension of `android.app.Fragment` in the API 11+ package. That being said, there is an [unofficial backport](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) that you may want to give a try. Alternatively, you could design a regular fragment to hold your preferences, but that would probably require some more work, or factor it out to a plain old `PreferencyActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer for anyone else that was wondering:

> The problem is dat getItem() wants you return an
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment, but an official PreferenceFragment
>   only exists as an extension of android.app.Fragment in the API 11+
>   package. That being said, there is an [unofficial backport][1] that
>   you may want to give a try. Alternatively, you could design a regular
>   fragment to hold your preferences, but that would probably require
>   some more work, or factor it out to a plain old PreferencyActivity.
>
> the backport - https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

Thanks to MH for the answer. All you have to do is download the backport and add it as a library resource to your project, then import the android.support.v4 thing INSTEAD OF the android.app thing.

Hope this helps everyone like it helped me :)